# Group multiple columns with different size inputs

Tags: html, css

I have a large number of inputs I need to display. I am trying to condense them into like groups.  The first group I am have is going to have 6 inputs in 3 columns but the third input box is big, so I want the next rows input to line up with the bottom of the larger text box.  [Form Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMUqw.png)

I have tried to float them, list them, use a table, but all without successs

I have looked at a lot of CSS code snippets and cannot figure out how to get this layout.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  I found a way to make it work, but would like a more elegant solution.  HTML:

```css
    .row1 {
        float: left;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .row2{
        float: left;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .row3{
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        clear: left;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -80px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row1">
                    <label>
                        <span>Full Project Number</span><br>
                        <input type="text" name="project" id="project">
                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
                    <label>
                        <span>Client</span><br>
                        <input type="text" name="client" id="client">
                    </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row2 fasttimesatseedmonthigh">
            <label id="descrp">
                <span>Project Description</span><br>
                <textarea name="name" type="text" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row3">
            <div class="row1">
                <label for="drawing">
                        <span>Drawing Number</span><br>
                        <input type="text" name="drawing" id="drawing">
                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
                <label>
                        <span>Assigned By:</span><br>
                        <input type="text" name="assigned" id="assigned" style="width: 75px;">
                    </label>
            </div>
            <div class="row1">
                <label class="form-row">
                        <span>Date</span><br>
                        <?php
                        $stamp=date("Y/m/d");?>
                        <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo(htmlspecialchars($stamp))?>"/>
                    </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It works but like I said not as nice as I would like it.

Comment: Do you want to do what's on the picture?

Comment: [it looks like a grid system - click me, I'm a link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Yes I want it to look like what it looks like in the pictures. I added code that works but I don't think it is the best.

Comment: I am looking into grids as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about a good ol' table with row&colspan?

```css
.grid{
 border: solid 1px black;
 table-layout: fixed;
 font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
 border-spacing: 10px;
}

.grid td{
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;
 font-size: 9pt;
}
.grid td.wide{
 width: 200px;
}
.grid td.normal{
 width: 100px;
}
.grid td input{
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="grid">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" class="wide">
   <label>
    <span>Full Project Number</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="project" id="project">
   </label>
  </td>
  <td colspan="2" class="wide">
   <label>
     <span>Client</span><br>
     <input type="text" name="client" id="client">
    </label>
  </td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
   <label id="descrp">
             <span>Project Description</span><br>
             <textarea name="name" type="text"  cols="20" rows="8"></textarea>
            </label>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="1" class="normal">
   <label for="drawing">
    <span>Drawing Number</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="drawing" id="drawing">
   </label>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" class="normal">
   <label>
    <span>Assigned By</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="assigned" id="assigned">
   </label>
  </td>
  <td colspan="2" class="wide">
   <label class="form-row">
    <span>Date</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date">
   </label>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Plis no hate.

Comment: It works fine, but can it scale down?  It looked like the grid layout was able to scale.

Comment: Well sure, you can adjust the width of the 'td.wide' and 'td.normal' class. The rest should be flexible.